# How to make this web page space-optimized using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this tiny web page:
[image]

This is the source code:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    body {
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h4 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h5 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h6 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    hr {
      height: 3px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border-width: 0;
      color: lightgray;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: darkgray;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding: 6px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    
    .button:visited {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .button:active {
      color: white;
    }
    
    a {
      color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body nyxt-identifier="0">
  <style nyxt-identifier="1">
    body {
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h4 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h5 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    h6 {
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    hr {
      height: 3px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border-width: 0;
      color: lightgray;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: darkgray;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding: 6px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    
    .button:visited {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .button:active {
      color: white;
    }
    
    a {
      color: gray;
    }
  </style>
  <h1 nyxt-identifier="2">Bindings</h1>
  <p nyxt-identifier="3">
  </p>
  <div nyxt-identifier="4">
    <h3 nyxt-identifier="5">override-map</h3>
    <table nyxt-identifier="6">
      <tbody nyxt-identifier="7">
        <tr nyxt-identifier="8">
          <td nyxt-identifier="9">C-S
          </td>
          <td nyxt-identifier="10">search-buffers
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr nyxt-identifier="11">

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div nyxt-identifier="44">
    <h3 nyxt-identifier="45">web-cua-map</h3>
    <table nyxt-identifier="46">
      <tbody nyxt-identifier="47">
        <tr nyxt-identifier="48">
          <td nyxt-identifier="49">f3
          </td>
          <td nyxt-identifier="50">search-buffer
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr nyxt-identifier="51">

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div nyxt-identifier="195">
    <h3 nyxt-identifier="196">base-cua-map</h3>
    <table nyxt-identifier="197">
      <tbody nyxt-identifier="198">
        <tr nyxt-identifier="199">
          <td nyxt-identifier="200">f5
          </td>
          <td nyxt-identifier="201">reload-current-buffer
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr nyxt-identifier="202">

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

The code and image above are a *simplification* of the real problem. In the real problem, the page is way bigger because the table has more elements than the currently shown.

I would like to use the space in a better way so that printing it would not spend too much paper. There is a lot of space being wasted on the right side of the screen.

The content could be more widespread horizontally instead of **only** vertically.

Two feasible approaches to achieve this goal would be (i) reducing the font-size, and (ii) making the table be a 2 column-table or 3-column instead of 1-column.

OK. I can reduce the font-size with CSS:

```
tr { font-size: 10px}
```

Thus, I would like to ask:

1 - How to make the table be 3-column or 2-column table using **CSS**?

I tried this approach following the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-span) on W3C:

```css
table {
  column-span: all;
}
```

But it did not work out.

2 - Would you have any suggestions beyond the font and column number tweak to maximize the use of space and reduce the use of paper?

Comment: The CSS is invalid; Font names that have spaces must be enclosed in quote marks. Also you do not need to use separate rules for each of `h1` through `h6`; it could just be `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica; font-weight: 500; }`.

Comment: You can use print media query (@media print) to add specific rules for printing pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not complicated at all. You just have to put all the key bindings and headings in **one** table instead of each in it's own. Then, we use a little bit of CSS to get a small border line between the table cells - just remove the CSS part if you don't want a border. Like this:

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bindings</h1>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        override-map
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        web-cua-map
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        base-cua-map
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        C-S
      </td>
      <td>
        search-buffers
      </td>
      <td>
        F3
      </td>
      <td>
        search-buffer
      </td>
      <td>
        F5
      </td>
      <td>
        reload-current-buffer
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```